# Difference between Angular CLI and Angular CDN

Tags: angular, angular-cli

What is the difference between running Angular CLI and using Angular from CDN? How and when it is compiled, in both the cases? It would be very helpful, if someone can explain in details.

Answer (score 2):

Angular CLI is a command line tool that your run ... In your command line.

Angular CDN is a set of files that you can add to your `<head>` tag to add the Angualr dependency to your project (I've never heard of it, but it's a CDN so the concept is the same)

I'm assuming you're using Typescript, which means your files will be compiled when you compile your Typescript.

The difference is that the CLI creates all the boilerplate code you will need, while you will have to write it when you use the CDN.

(This is how I see it, but I might be wrong since I have never used Angular's CDN)

Comment: Can i look into it like this? For Angular CLI its AOT compilation and for Angular CDN it is JIT compilation.

Comment: Nope. Angular CLI can (or maybe could) compile in JIT mode, and the CDN are Javascript files, so they aren't compiled at all (well they're compiled, but not by you)

Comment: But in Angular CDN, Angular compiler is also being downloaded to compile and generate the DOM.
In Angular CLI do we send compiled code (compiled in server side) or send the angular compiler over network for client side compilation ?

Comment: I can't speak for the CDN so I won't comment on your first statement, only tell you that I don't think so (but I'm probably wrong). On the second statement, you compile your code in JS files (that contain JS, HTML and CSS), which are then sent to a server that serves them through your `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

**Cdn** -

1. Well angular cdn or any cdn(content delivery network) link is used to host our files to the server... So that we can run our web app without downloading the files required for angular.js to run. 
   2.I think cdn is only available for angular.js not for angular 2+
2. You need internet connection in order run youra web app
   As cdn can work only when there is internet connection 
   angular cdn look like this:
   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js

Its the hosted code

**Cli** -

Now angular cli (command line interface) or any cli which is mostly run by npm is used to download the files containing code which will be required to run the angular app 
Cli consist of different commands to be typed on terminal
for eg to install the angular---

```
 npm install angular
```

The download angular files i.e.  in case of cli own apps compile and run faster as doesn't depend on internet connection where as in cdn we should have fast in internet connection to run it properly

Hope the above explanation make you understand how angular work in both the cases. Let me know if you have any other doubts

Comment: In Angular CDN i can download the source file and host it in my server and add it in script tag. In that way it will not be required to have internet connection. 
How and when the compilation happens in Angular CLI and Angular CDN?

Comment: in both cases compilation occurs at runtime i guess ..... but we dont need to worry about that background process